# HTML email body truncation while sending email from outlook using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation

I have one HTML file which i want to send from PowerShell using outlook. I have used below code however it is truncating the email body after 603 chars, hence only upper half of the html page is going as body in outllook email.

```
$body = Get-Content -Path .\\Output.html  #this have around 1500 chars.
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "xyz@abc.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Daily Dump Status"
$body.ToString()
$Mail.HTMLBody = $body  # while coping the data only 603 char are going into body.
$Mail.Send()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal\]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
```

I have also tried options like  Out-String while coping but didnt work

Comment: If you log the `$body` variable (e.g. to a file), do you see the whole string? Are you sure you don't have a binary 0x0 in your string?

Comment: yes, $body was printing the entire message however $Mail.HTMLBody was printing only 603 chars. the issue caused by a NUL in the html file.

Comment: When you use the right `-Encoding` in `Get-Content`, does that improve things?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of data you could set for a property. In the Outlook object model string properties are limited in size depending on the information store type.

To bridge the gap you need to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI which allows opening properties with stream for writing huge amount of data. The [IMAPIProp::OpenProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapiprop-openproperty) method provides access to a property through a particular interface. `OpenProperty` is an alternative to the `IMAPIProp::GetProps` and `IMAPIProp::SetProps` methods. When either `GetProps` or `SetProps` fails because the property is too large or too complex, call `OpenProperty`.

You may also take a look at the famous and popular wrapper around Extended MAPI - the Redemption library.

Comment: Thanks for reply, however my code is working fine if i provide hardcoded html as input instead of reading it from file . So length is not an issue.

Comment: Try adding the -raw parameter to your call to get-content. This was suggested to me by another SO member to solve a problem with reading xml files.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours, finally got the root cause of this issue. The html page which i was trying to sent as email body was the output of another powershell command using  ConvertTo-Html. And the output of PowerShell command had "NUL" in it.

```
$Mail.HTMLBody = $body
```

Hence above command was coping the data till first "NUL". I identified this by opening the html page in notepad++. Issue got resolved after replacing NUL with " "